# How to create reusable horizontal scroll widget which contains image ,text and subtext? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to create a horizontal scrolling widget which contains an image text and subtext which  should be reusable

[image: a row with image a text and subtext]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a horizontally scrollable listView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 10,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return customCard(index);
        },
      ),
    ) ;
  }
}
Widget customCard(int index){
  return Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
    child: ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.person),// here you used image
      title: Text("title $index"),
      subtitle: Text("Subtitle $index"),
    ),
  );
}
```

Output:

[image]